# Loop In Crystal Reports C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i want to print the specific column using loop in crystal report.
like i want that all the ammount shows one by one using loop where username is abc and date is XYZ on crystal report in c#
example
table have 3 columns ..
date , name , fees

i want to show the data on crystal report like fees repeat where name and date matched

name : abc
date : 03/03/2016
Fees : 300
Fees : 300

Comment: @BugFinder yes i am doing lots of work in crystal report , my whole system reporting is on crystal report .. but i am stucked into this issue

Comment: Give sample data and also how to want to show in report

Comment: Give us some code.